# Binding list parameter with Django 1.3 ORM raw query

Tags: python, django, binding, orm

How to bind list in Django 1.3 ORM raw query?
Example what i want:

```
customers = [1, 2, 3]
# ....
customers_filter = "and products.customer_id in (%(customers)s)"
sql_params['customers'] = customers # <<< how to bind list?
# ....
cursor.execute(sql, sql_params)
```

Comment: Why dont you want to use the ORM itself ? Why Raw queries ?

Comment: Sorry, i mean that i use connection to db over django db cursor. Raw queries - because i have difficult logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example, how i solve that problem

```
total = {}

if customers:
    sql_params.update({'customer_%s' % index: customer for index, customer in enumerate(customers)})
    customers_filter = 'and t.customer_id in (%s)' % ', '.join(
        '%%(customer_%s)s' % index for index, customer in enumerate(customers))
```